# How can I emit types with custom prefixes and custom casing when using Apollo Codegen?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

We are using https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/developer-tooling/#apollo-codegen.
I am wondering if it is possible to generate types/interfaces for TypeScript with a custom prefix & casing? For example, let's say we have a .graphql file:

```
query homePage {
  user {
    id
  }
}
```

When we run the script to generate type defs we end up with this:

```
export interface homePage {
  user: homePage_user | null; 
}
```

However, what we'd actually like is:

```
export interface THomePage {
  user: THomePage_user | null; 
}
```

Is this possible?

Our current script to generate the code is: `"apollo client:codegen --includes=**/*.ts.graphql --endpoint=http://localhost:3100 --tsFileExtension=d.ts --target=typescript --globalTypesFile=src/__generated__/Types.d.ts --passthroughCustomScalars --customScalarsPrefix=GQL."`

Comment: Have you found a solution for this @mike?

Comment: No I have not (but I also haven't spent any further energy on trying to find a solution)